# Error "Undefined control sequence" when using [remember picture, overlay]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am using two `tikzpicture` inside another `tikzpicture`. I want to draw a arrow from one picture to the other. For that I used `[remember picture, overlay]` property as shown in the code below.

### New Code

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{above_background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{background,above_background,main}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[cloud, cloud puffs=16, minimum width=8cm, minimum height=3cm, draw] (cloud) at (0,0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}    

    \node[] {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

            \node[draw] (node1) at (0,0) {Node 1};
            \node[draw] (node2) at (0,-1.5) {Node 2};
            \node[draw] (node3) at (0,-3) {Node 3};
            \node[draw] (node4)  at (0,-4.5) {Node 4};

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
                \path (node1.west |- node1.north)+(-0.3,0.8) node (a) {};
                \path (node4.south -| node4.east)+(2.5,-1) node (b) {};
                \path[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
                (a) rectangle (b);
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{above_background}
                \path (node1.west |- node1.north)+(-0.5,1) node (a) {};
                \path (node4.south -| node4.east)+(1.2,-1.5) node (b) {};
                \path[fill=black!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50,dashdotted]
                (a) rectangle (b);
            \end{pgfonlayer}


        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{1cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

            \node[draw] (node5) at (0,0) {Node 5};
            \node[draw] (node6) at (0,-1.5) {Node 6};
            \node[draw] (node7) at (0,-3) {Node 7};
            \node[draw] (node8)  at (0,-4.5) {Node 8};

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
                \path (node5.west |- node5.north)+(-0.3,0.8) node (a) {};
                \path (node8.south -| node8.east)+(2.5,-1) node (b) {};
                \path[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed]
                (a) rectangle (b);
            \end{pgfonlayer}

            \begin{pgfonlayer}{above_background}
                \path (node5.west |- node5.north)+(-0.5,1) node (a) {};
                \path (node8.south -| node8.east)+(1.2,-1.5) node (b) {};
                \path[fill=black!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50,dashdotted]
                (a) rectangle (b);
            \end{pgfonlayer}


            \draw[->,draw=black] (node5) to (node1);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

### Old Code

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[] {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

            \node[draw] (node1) at (0,0) {Node 1};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{1cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

            \node[draw] (node2) at (2,2) {Node 2};

            \draw[->,draw=black] (node2) to (node1);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I am getting the following error when I compile the above picture in **TeXnicCenter** and also in **TeXstudio**

```
!Undefined control sequence.
1.61 \savepicturepage
                {pgfid2}{15}
```

I have tried deleting the .aux file and recompiling it again but still the problem persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you complicate things? What you need can be achieved in a simpler way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,auto]
  \node[draw] (node1) at (0,0) {Node 1};
  \node[draw] (node2) at (3,2) {Node 2};  %% instead of hspace, I used 3 as x-coordinate.
  \draw[->,draw=black] (node2) to (node1);
\end{tikzpicture}
%Some text here whose position won't be affected by the \verb|{tikzpicture}|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also there is no need to use `remember picture` if you don't use coordinates like `current page.north east` etc.

Reducing the complications further a little, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes, backgrounds, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning, fit, petri, tikzmark}

\pgfdeclarelayer{cloud}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{above_background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}
\pgfsetlayers{cloud,background,above_background,main}

\tikzset{component/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em,
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[draw] (node1) [component] at (0,0) {Node 1};
    \node[draw] (node2) [component] at (0,-1.5) {Node 2};
    \node[draw] (node3) [component] at (0,-3) {Node 3};
    \node[draw] (node4) [component]  at (0,-4.5) {Node 4};

    \node[draw,right=5cm of node1] (node5) [component]  {Node 5};
    \node[draw,right=5cm of node2] (node6) [component]  {Node 6};
    \node[draw,right=5cm of node3] (node7) [component]  {Node 7};
    \node[draw,right=5cm of node4] (node8) [component]  {Node 8};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{above_background}
       \node[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed,fit=(node1)(node4),
         inner sep=10pt]  (left1)  {};
       \node[fill=yellow!20,rounded corners, draw=black!50, dashed,fit=(node5)(node8),
         inner sep=10pt]  (right1)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
       \node[fill=black!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50,dashdotted,fit=(left1),
             inner sep=10pt]  (left2)  {};
       \node[fill=black!10,rounded corners, draw=black!50,dashdotted,fit=(right1),
             inner sep=10pt]  (right2)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    %% this is also possible
%    \begin{pgfonlayer}{cloud}
%        \node[cloud, cloud puffs=16,fit=(node1)(node8), draw] (cloud) {};
%    \end{pgfonlayer}
%% or this
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{cloud}
        \node[cloud, cloud puffs=16,minimum width=14cm, minimum height=8cm, draw] (cloud)
            at ($(left2)!0.5!(right2)$)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \draw[->,draw=black] (node5) to (node1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the generous reply, I have added my complete code and it was the reason I am having these nested tikzpictures and getting the same error. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: @AbdurRahman You have complicated it all :-) But your new code compiles for me. So I can't trace the problem. Anyway, nesting tikzpicture inside node is *not* a good idea.

Comment: So should I make columns and place the `tikzpicture` inside it?

Comment: I am editing the tikzpicture in an online editor. Here is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/2178831gkmcnc) to it. Kindly see if I am using current page coordinates correctly. Thanks

Comment: @AbdurRahman No! See the edited answer.